# How to get transparent drive or folder compression for Ext4 partition used by Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, linux-mint, ext4

I know of the following transparent drive compressions on other operating systems:

- MS-DOS 6.22 Doublespace (configured by autoexec.bat or config.sys)
- Windiws XP/7: Drive Compression (configured by right-click on a folder in the file browser)

How to get transparent drive compression on Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint?

Possible, they are a solutions based on one of the follow one:

- a more modern ext5 file system in future https://www.phoronix.com/news/MTIxNTE
- a partly ZFS; BTRFS and and with the introduction of kernel 6.7 with bcachefs, function on top of ext4
- a compression like lz4 on top of ext4
- Fusecompress
- LessFS
- https://lwn.net/Articles/561650/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20221214235440/https://lwn.net/Articles/561650/

Answer (score 16):

ext4 doesn't support compression, for that you need to use either [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression) or [ZFS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS) (available in Ubuntu [since 19.10](https://ubuntu.com/blog/zfs-focus-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-whats-new) but it's still experimental).

Compression can be also configured on block device level with [Device mapper VDO](https://github.com/dm-vdo/kvdo) and than you could use it with ext4 (because it doesn't matter what filesystem is on top of the device), but that's currently [not supported in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1869825).

Answer (score 4):

You can compress and read/write a folder on ext4 p.e. by [fuse-zip](https://bitbucket.org/agalanin/fuse-zip/src/master/) (*a FUSE filesystem for zip archives with write support*):

```
sudo mkdir -v /home/user/my_compressed_folder
```

Mount

```
mount /home/user/my_compressed_folder/zipArchive

fuse-zip foobar.zip /home/user/my_folder/zipArchive
```

Unmount

```
fusermount -u /home/user/my_compressed_folder/zipArchive
```

For additional information see: https://linux.die.net/man/1/fuse-zip

Comment: (1) Why do you need `sudo` to create a sub-directory in your user's home directory? (2) Are you sure it's `mount /home/.../zipArchive`, and not `mkdir /home/.../zipArchive` in your "mount" section (in particular when looking at the linked man-page)?

Comment: If I remember right, it only worked with sudo on my test system.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint on NTFS if you like. NTFS supports transparent drive compressing like btrfs, ZFS and and with the introduction of kernel 6.7 with bcachefs.

"According to the mount.ntfs-3g(8) manual page ( https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ntfs-3g/mount.ntfs-3g.8.en.html ):

```
This option enables creating new transparently compressed files in directories marked for compression. A directory is marked for compression by setting the bit 11 (value 0x00000800) in its Windows attribute. In such a directory, new files are created compressed and new subdirectories are themselves marked for compression. The option and the flag have no effect on existing files.
```

The compression option merely enables support for compression. You will still have to mark the individual directories as compressed in order for this to have any effect.

Even without this filesystem option, existing compressed files can still be read and modified."

Source: [How to enable compression as mount option in /etc/fstab for ntfs-3g formatted disk under Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649747/how-to-enable-compression-as-mount-option-in-etc-fstab-for-ntfs-3g-formatted-di)